# char cannot be dereferenced in java?

Tags: java

```
static char guessLetter (String lettersGuessed)
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println ("Guess a letter: ");
  char letterGuessed = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

  if (letterGuessed.isLetter())
  {
    return letterGuessed;
  }
  else 
  {
    System.out.println ("That is not a letter. Please try typing a letter again.");
```

How do I fix this it is giving me an error "char cannot be dereferenced"

I am not sure what that means.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char` is a primitive type so you can't call methods on it. Also, [`Character.isLetter(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) takes a char argument, so I think you wanted something like this

```
char letterGuessed = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
if (Character.isLetter(letterGuessed)) { // <-- the if test.
  return letterGuessed;
}
```